Getting the below error in Playwright (Python) when trying to upload a file : Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory
Everything works until the point of uploading a file. It's an automation of uploading a file with its own unique file path. I use the data from the csv file being uploaded to create the unique file path for each loop instance. The error I get every time is: FileChooser.set_files: ENOENT: no such file or directory, access '/Users/dani/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/MCS-150 (Reactivate)/123456/Screenshot-2024-09-15-at-2.16.42 AM.png
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
import time
import csv


file_path = '/Users/dani/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Jotform Downloads/Jotform_Reactivate_Submissions.csv'

with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(csv_reader)
    for line in csv_reader:
        


        with sync_playwright() as p:
            browser = p.webkit.launch(headless=False, args=["--start-maximized"])
            page = browser.new_page(no_viewport=True)
            page.goto("https://ask.fmcsa.dot.gov/app/ticket")
            page.set_default_timeout(60000)

            page.wait_for_load_state('networkidle')
            
            page.locator('xpath=//*[@id="rn_TextInput_5_Contact.Emails.PRIMARY.Address"]').fill('building.wealth@icloud.com')
            page.locator('xpath=//*[@id="rn_TextInput_7_Contact.Name.First"]').fill(line[0])
            page.locator('xpath=//*[@id="rn_TextInput_9_Contact.Name.Last"]').fill(line[1])
            page.locator('xpath=//*[@id="rn_TextInput_11_Incident.CustomFields.c.dot_number"]').fill(line[2])
            page.locator('xpath=//*[@id="rn_TextInput_13_Incident.CustomFields.c.mc_number"]').fill(line[3])
            page.locator('xpath=//*[@id="rn_ProductCategoryInputSimpleFiltered_20_Incident.Product_lvl1"]').select_option('USDOT Number')
            page.locator('xpath=//*[@id="rn_ProductCategoryInputSimpleFiltered_20_Incident.Product_lvl2"]').select_option('Reactivate my USDOT Number')
            time.sleep(15)
            
            
            ID_path = ('/Users/dani/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/MCS-150 (Reactivate)/{}/{}'.format(line[2], line[4]))
            LLC_path = ('/Users/dani/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/MCS-150 (Reactivate)/{}/{}'.format(line[2], line[5]))
            
            print(ID_path)
            print(LLC_path)

            with page.expect_file_chooser() as fc_info:
                page.get_by_label("Attach Documents").click()
                file_chooser = fc_info.value
                file_chooser.is_multiple()
                file_chooser.set_files(ID_path)
                time.sleep(10)
                file_chooser.set_files(LLC_path)
              
                
            
            time.sleep(30)
          

            browser.close()

The code will work if I manually enter the file path like this but of course I don't want it to loop to the same file path.
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
import time
import csv


file_path = '/Users/dani/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Jotform Downloads/Jotform_Reactivate_Submissions.csv'

with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(csv_reader)
    for line in csv_reader:
        


        with sync_playwright() as p:
            browser = p.webkit.launch(headless=False, args=["--start-maximized"])
            page = browser.new_page(no_viewport=True)
            page.goto("https://ask.fmcsa.dot.gov/app/ticket")
            page.set_default_timeout(60000)

            page.wait_for_load_state('networkidle')
            
            page.locator('xpath=//*[@id="rn_TextInput_5_Contact.Emails.PRIMARY.Address"]').fill('building.wealth@icloud.com')
            page.locator('xpath=//*[@id="rn_TextInput_7_Contact.Name.First"]').fill(line[0])
            page.locator('xpath=//*[@id="rn_TextInput_9_Contact.Name.Last"]').fill(line[1])
            page.locator('xpath=//*[@id="rn_TextInput_11_Incident.CustomFields.c.dot_number"]').fill(line[2])
            page.locator('xpath=//*[@id="rn_TextInput_13_Incident.CustomFields.c.mc_number"]').fill(line[3])
            page.locator('xpath=//*[@id="rn_ProductCategoryInputSimpleFiltered_20_Incident.Product_lvl1"]').select_option('USDOT Number')
            page.locator('xpath=//*[@id="rn_ProductCategoryInputSimpleFiltered_20_Incident.Product_lvl2"]').select_option('Reactivate my USDOT Number')
            time.sleep(15)
            
            
            ID_path = ('/Users/dani/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/MCS-150 (Reactivate)/{}/{}'.format(line[2], line[4]))
            LLC_path = ('/Users/dani/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/MCS-150 (Reactivate)/{}/{}'.format(line[2], line[5]))
            
            print(ID_path)
            print(LLC_path)

            with page.expect_file_chooser() as fc_info:
                page.get_by_label("Attach Documents").click()
                file_chooser = fc_info.value
                file_chooser.is_multiple()
                file_chooser.set_files('/Users/dani/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/MCS-150 (Reactivate)/123456/Screenshot-2024-09-15-at-2.16.42 AM.png')
                time.sleep(10)
                file_chooser.set_files('/Users/dani/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/MCS-150 (Reactivate)/123456/IMAGE-2024-09-1-at-2.16.55 AM.png')
              
                
            
            time.sleep(30)
          

            browser.close()


Avoid XPath in favor of accessible locators like get_by_role or at least CSS selectors. Ids in CSS selectors can be simply #your-id. Anyway, in the interests of a [mcve], it seems like this question is totally unrelated to Playwright, just a file issue with vanilla Python. The problem just boils down to making those formatted strings match the ones you're hardcoding.

You’re absolutely right, I will do the change. Thanks for the tip

Your filename in the second version include a unicode Narrow No-Break Space (U+202F) that is not the same as the normal space you generated in your first code. So the filename with a normal space doesn't exist in your filesystem.

I understand thanks for pointing that out. How would you go about changing the normal space to that Unicode Narrow No-Break Space in my csv data using python ?

@user28538867 In Python you can do "\u202f". Regarding your codes, since you read the file path from a csv file, I recommend updating that csv file as well. Also you can try to use os.listdir() in Python to get the actual value of filenames.

Thank you! This literally fixed everything.
